# how to combine (merge) trainded data of Tesseract files

Tags: c++, tesseract

I have trained new font for english language with Tesseract OCR (JavaTessBoxEditor)
I received:
eng.trainddata
inttemp
normproto
pffmtable
shapetable
unicharset
files

I've tried to make combine_data, but nothing changed to main eng.traindeddata file. It was not not amended.

Then I've tried to download 3rd Party Software (QT version from Zdenko, GUI from General Delopment NL)
No result still

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it seem to be combined with combine_tessdata -o C:\tesseract-ocr\tessdata C:\Users\66820\Desktop\gimp/eng.traineddata, but the it does not recognize characters as I trained